# prevent pages in web.config according to user member

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership

I am using custom user membership in asp.NET so user is an object that contains members. One of the user's members is "IsCompanyAdmin".
I have a few aspx pages for company administrators only.
Is there any way to prevent those pages from non-administrator users using the web.config?

Comment: are you using a custom role provider as well?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net the standard fair for restricting access to pages in the config is via the [Location element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx).

The following example will restrict anyone except users who are in the Admin role. However, this assumes that you have a [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) configured.

```
<location path="RestrictedPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

There are [several examples](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=custom+role+provider+asp.net) of how to implement your own custom role provider, but if you can get away with it, then I would use the built in [SqlRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx).

Comment: I don't have Admin role and I prefer not to make one. My seperation to roles is by modules: Module1, Module2,... Admin is not a module so I create a member in user object that tells if user is an admin.

Comment: The only other way around this would be to create your own HttpModule to load information from web.config, and then check incoming requests, restricting access based on your custom membership object. It's really not terribly difficult albeit a little tedious.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you don't have to have a role in database.

What can do is in your CustomRoleProvider GetRolesForUser method return a string[] that will contain roles depending on your user. The authorization module will be using these roles. So say your property IsCompanyAdmin="true" then you add "Admin" to the string[].

Then the location suggestion provided by Josh should work as if you have a "Admin" role in database.

Comment: Correct, all the security checks are done based on the Principal object that gets bound to the current thread. And just to note that the role can be whatever you want it to be... "Bob", "Larry", etc...

Comment: @Naor: Sorry, may be I am not completely understanding that Module part. Do you mind explaining it a little more?